# Safely storing and output data

Tags: php, mysql

On my application I use this method to store and to output the data.  I would like to know if it is safely and correct.

```
##store the data###
//sanitize
function clean($testo)
{
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $testo = $purifier->purify($testo);

    $testo = mysql_real_escape_string($testo);
    return $testo;
}
$value = clean($_POST[value]);
//the clean function contain mysql_real_escape_string and htmlpurifier class
$sql = mysql_query("insert into table values(null,$value);");

##output the data####
$sql = mysql_query("select * from table");
$val = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
function echoValue($valore){
    $valore = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes($valore)), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    return $valore;

}
echo echoValue($val);
// the echoValue function contain strip_tags and htmlentities
```

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated. Instead use `PDO` or `mysqli`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: [**Read up on the subject**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection) because it is not.

Comment: And it is impossible to answer without knowing what clean looks like

Comment: Both functions seems to falsify the content. I don't consider this as a "correct" behaviour. No need to add something about using mysql_* functions in new code.

Comment: i have add the code of the two functions

Comment: This shouldn't even work, missing quotes around `$value` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

To "Safely" store data, please don't use `mysql_*` functions. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Also, use `PreparedStatements` wherever you use "`where`" clause in queries. That will protect you against injection.

https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: it is a huge application, to convert everything into PDO will take long time, there is not other ways? to fix this code?

Comment: There's no other way. I personally did many such things to achieve security and clean code. Better be safe than sorry.

Comment: wich is more easy to convert mysqli o pdo? thanks

Comment: Both are easy. I would prefer PDO.